# python gets stuck loading page with mechanize

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

While using mechanize to open and process a lot pages (1000+) on a website I have hit a strange problem. Every now and then I get stuck trying to load a page, without timing out, the problem doesn't seem to be page specific as if I run it again and try to open the same page it works as a charm, but rather seem to happen at random.

I'm using this function to open pages

```
def openMechanize(br, url):
    while True:
        try:
            print time.localtime()
            print "opening: " + url

            resp = br.open(url, timeout = 2.5)

            print "done\n"

            return resp

        except Exception, errormsg:
            print repr(errormsg)

            print "failed to load page, retrying"
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

When it gets stuck it makes the first print, current time and opening url, but never gets to the second one. I have tried to let it run for hours but nothing happens.

When interrupting the script with ctrl+c while it is stuck I get the following output:

```
  File "test.py", line 143, in openMechanize
    resp = br.open(url, timeout = 2.5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 193, in open
    response = urlopen(self, req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1142, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1116, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Upon inspecting socket.py, where it gets stuck, I see the following:

```
        self._rbuf = StringIO()  # reset _rbuf.  we consume it via buf.
        while True:
            try:
                data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
            except error, e:
                if e.args[0] == EINTR:
                    continue
                raise
```

Looks like it gets stuck in an endless loop as recv for some reason crashes

Has anyone experienced this error and found some sort of fix?

Comment: Did you get 'done' printed out?

Comment: no, not when it gets stuck. It can work for between a dozen to thousands of pages and then just stop

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the specific URL?

Comment: have tried putting the url that it gets stuck on first and run again, it then works as expected. Appears to happen at random